# Is CodedUI Suitable for Performance Testing ? What are the Disadvantages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, desktop-application, performance-testing, coded-ui-tests, baseline

I have created few Automated Tests to test the Large scale Desktop application written using MFC & WPF technology. UI tests execute consistently, now can we use the same tests to measure the performance of the loading of the UI/Controls ? I am adding the stopwatch before clicking a button and stopping it once I see the next screen. Similarly for other controls/Windows. In this way I plan to run this tests after each new build of the Application and compare the performance.

Few challenges I am observing
1) Every time I execute the tests I get different numbers. So not able to figure out the base line
2) From Coded UI End there are few waiters that will influence these differences
3) What should be my logic to take a baseline that is more predictable and measurable ?

Or using the CodedUI for performance test is bad Idea ? Any thoughts on this are very much appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking to analyze performance, why aren't you using the performance tools that come with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I can only talk from WinForms experience using DevExpress controls.

Basically the performance leaves a lot to be desired. The main performance issues are with complex UI's that feature a lot of nested layout controls.

Playback in Coded UI uses a nested chain lookup system in a WinForms application. This means that you can't simply search for a control by Id, but need to go through a parent->child hierarchy (Aka "search limiters).

I can imagine that playback would be considerably faster for web where you could search directly on the DOM by Id of the controls for an exact match.

Next huge performance issue is Grids and Trees. Or controls that have rows / columns. Here, in Winforms every time you want to **"reliably"** get the control, the test engine does a full lookup to the control. This makes it slow.

My advice would be using the recorder locate a deeply nested grid control in your WPF application. Once it's in the UI map then write code to iterate through all items in the control - test both setting and getting dynamically.

You might be happy with the performance. I've found ways to get around performance by using native Win32 methods here and thought about just using Click paths for navigation, this way eliminating the need to lookup at least the nav controls, but this would require extra maintenance if the UI changes.

One thing I can say is, the best performance I've found is:

```
private static WaitForReadyLevel _waitLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;

Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 12000;
Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls = false;
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = _waitLevel;
Playback.PlaybackSettings.DelayBetweenActions = 100;
Mouse.MouseDragSpeed = 9000;
```

Hope this helps.